# Compare cells in VBA for conditional formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I have this chunk of code that works just fine:

```
Function sshProblem(rng As Range) As Boolean
   Dim portStatus As String
   portStatus = rng.Value

   Dim deviceType As String
   deviceType = Cells(Application.Caller.Row, 3).Value

   Dim sshDevices As Variant
   sshDevices = Array("linux", "vmw", "docker", "unix")

   If StrComp(portStatus, "No") = 0 Then
      sshProblem = Not IsError(Application.Match(deviceType, sshDevices, 0))
   End If
End Function
```

Now the code needs to scale, and instead of storing values inside the sshDevices array, these values need to reside in a column in another sheet, so I tried to replace

```
sshDevices = Array("linux", "vmw", "docker", "unix")
```

with

```
sshDevices = Worksheets("Config sheet").Range("I2:I11").Value
```

at that point the conditional formatting stopped working. How may I pick up the values from a cell range and insert them into a variable for comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure with what you are trying to achieve with your code, but to answer your question

> How may I pick up the values from a cell range and insert them into a variable for comparison?

you can use a `For Each` loop, something akin to:

```
dim myCell as range, myRange as range
set myRange = Worksheets("Config sheet").Range("I2:I11")

For Each myCell in myRange
    sshDevice = myCell.Value
    'do stuff you need with sshDevice
Next myCell
```

If you want to keep the sshDevices array, you can do that, and use the `For Each` loop to add each item individually.

```
dim counter as int
counter = 0
For Each myCell in myRange
    sshDevice(counter) = myCell.Value
    counter = counter + 1
next myCell
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
sshDevices = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Config sheet").Range("I2:I11").Value)
```

just be informed that this way you'll have a *1-based* array regardless of any `Option Base` which however affects the returned array form `Array()` function

Comment: Neither suggestion is working people. The conditional formatting is not taking place. Not sure if the array is being imported correctly or if the code chunk used for the comparison is compatible with the array types Im using

Comment: Well, your post was about how to store values in `sshDevices`  array from a range instead of hard coding them with the `Array() `function, complaining your attempt (`sshDevices = Worksheets("Config sheet").Range("I2:I11").Value`) didn't work since it stopped some conditional formatting you didn't post any information about. My answer  told you why your way of array range-filling wouldn't work as the "good" one and gave you the correct syntax to have an array returned from a "vertical" range working as your original `Array("linux", "vmw", "docker", "unix")` one. I think I answered your question